# How to read file without require('fs') - NodeJS

Tags: node.js

I've got a challenge to read a txt file that located in the same directory as my app.js.

In the challenge I can't use `require` so I can't import `fs.readFileSync` to my app.

Looking for other ways to `console.log` the txt content. Any ideas?

Comment: You'll have to find a system level `process` method that will read a stream for you

Comment: The can you use stackoverflow challenge? Great fun.

Comment: @SterlingArcher Are you sure that it's possible?

Comment: You can pipe a file to your process and use `process.stdin`

Comment: @ippi not sure that i understood what exactly do you mean..

Comment: `node index.js < hello.txt`  I'm not sure if I should give you the complete answer though...

Comment: How about you add a blindfold as well to make this interesting :p

Comment: Is this a user-defined challenge or a business use-case challenge?  If it's the latter, please provide *why* this is a challenge because it seems like it would be an XY problem in that case.

Comment: What is the point of this challenge so we can understand the real goal here.  Is this just a hacking challenge with no real-world point?  Or is there a real-world point here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without using `require` explicitly, you can use: `module.constructor._load` or `process.mainModule.constructor._load`

```
const fs = module.constructor._load('fs');
console.log(fs.readFileSync('./test.txt'));
```

Note that `process.mainModule` will be `undefined` if there is no entry script. (Not your case)

Of course this shouldn't be used in production code, since it's an undocumented API and may change. But will do for your challenge.

---

> forgot to mention that I have to run it as node app.js

Otherwise you could use ES6 modules too, but that requires an additional flag: `node --experimental-modules app.js`

Comment: There is also `process.binding('fs')` but I thought that was cheating, but I wonder if `process.dlopen()` is usable? I also tried to use `process.stdin.constructor` which is a [ReadStream](https://nodejs.org/api/tty.html#tty_class_tty_readstream) but for that you need a file descriptor and I couldn't figure it out and put it all on the shelf.

Comment: Well, I don't believe it's cheating if you're not using `require` :P. I don't believe you can do it with process.stdin.constructor, since it's not a `fs` ReadStream.

Comment: But it's derived from [net.Socket](https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_new_net_socket_options). shouldn't it be possible to use any file as a filesocket?

Comment: I'll let you know if it's possible, I'm going through the code.

Comment: I really appreciate you trying.I did fumble about in that rabbit hole for a while - but I'm only curious so don't waste too much time on my behalf.

Comment: You're welcome :), I don't now If I can try it tonight, but I'll definitely do it, I don't consider it a waste, this are the things that make you understand how node works, so I will update if I find a way.